# SQL where clause to find records containing mixed values in a sub-table

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, where-clause

I'm super new to SQL.

I am writing a fairly simple query and am stuck on something.

The company I work for transfers goods between different sites we keep track of these with two main tables. Table1 is the transfer header, Table2 is the goods that are being transferred. As the goods are being booked on at the receiving end this updates a status field in Table2 and when the whole transfer is booked on this updates the status in the header table.

I'm trying to find the header records for transfers that have not had every product booked on yet but have erroneously updated the header.

I struggling to get the WHERE clause correct, I have tried the following and variants of it with no luck.

```
select distinct Table1.ref_no, Table1.status, Table1.site_to
from Table1 with(nolock)
left join Table2 with(nolock)
on Table2.ref_no = Table1.ref_no 
where (Table2.status ='notbooked' and Table2.status ='booked')
```

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code; example input (as initialization code) with desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. For errors that includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) For SQL include DDL & tabular initialization. When you get a result you don't expect, pause your overall goal, chop to the 1st subexpression with unexpected result & say what you expected & why, justified by documentation.

Comment: LEFT JOIN returns INNER JOIN rows UNION ALL unmatched left table rows extended by NULLs. Always know what INNER JOIN you want as part of an OUTER JOIN. After a LEFT JOIN a WHERE, INNER JOIN or HAVING that requires a right [sic] table column to be not NULL removes any rows with introduced NULLs, ie leaves only INNER JOIN rows, ie "turns OUTER JOIN into INNER JOIN". You have that. PS This is a faq. But you have to write many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal to be able to search. PS Ask 1 specific researched non-duplicate question. [ask] [Help]

Comment: Stop splattering your code with [nolock](https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have a look at your where statement at the very least.

Table2.status can never be 'notbooked' and 'booked'

I would think you meant:

```
table2.status = 'notbooked' and table1.status = 'booked'
```

Comment: Hi Dave, thank you for taking time out to help me out.

I think that's all it was, achingly simple. I think thats cracked it. 

Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT Table2.ref_no FROM Table2 INNER JOIN Table1 ON Table2.ref_no = Table1.ref_no
WHERE Table2.status = 'notbooked' AND Table1.status = 'booked'
```

Comment: Hi, thank you so much. So so simple. Thank you.

Comment: If the answer is correct, you should marked as resolved